# Inline descriptions and automatic sorted glossary entries

Tags: glossaries, context

Is there any way to get `\definedescription` & `\setupdescriptions` to not only produce the inline description, but also an entry in a sorted glossary? Perhaps with `before=` & `after=` to add the commands for the glossary?

Comment: Not very clear. What do you want to exactly? Use the description environment and automate the insertion of terms in a glossary? Could you provide a small compilable code and give details?

Comment: This is exactly what I want.... to make one entry in the source file that produces an description where I placed it, and also adds that description to a sorted glossary. Unfortunately I cannot post a MWE, as I don't know how to make it work. Perhaps a new macro that invokes both facilities would work too.... The links from contextgarden to the source for Context seem to be broken, so I cannot even jump into the deep end.

Comment: Could you post a small *compilable* code of what you've tried that we  can play with?

Comment: Please post a MWE with your descriptions and your `definedescription` parameters

Answer (score 1):

Other than needing to resolve some "normal" formatting issues, I've found a solution....

```
\setuppapersize[letter]
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]
\setupwhitespace[medium]

\definedescription[conceptdesc][alternative=serried,headstyle=bold,width=broad]

\definesynonyms[conceptsyn][concepts][\expandconcept]
\setupsynonyms[conceptsyn][width=4cm, criterium=all]

\def\concept#1#2%
{
\conceptsyn{#1}{#2}
\index{#1}
\conceptdesc{#1}#2\par
}


\starttext 

\chapter{The Great Text}

\input lorem.tex

\concept{Catatonic Choochoo}{
The etherial vehicle one travels on when being 
kidnapped by friends.
}

\input lorem.tex

\concept{Application Binary Interface}{
In computer software, an application binary 
interface is an interface between two binary program modules; often, one of these modules is a library or operating system facility, and the other is a program that is being run by a user.
}

\input lorem.tex

\chapter{Concepts}
\placelistofconcepts

\chapter{Index}
\placeindex

\stoptext
```